# How to get the substring that contains the first N unicode characters in Java

Tags: java, unicode, substring

The String datatype in Java lets us know how many unicode chars exit in a string by codePointCount; and how to get the n-th unicode char by codePointAt. I was wonding if there is an API to get the substring that contains the first N unicode characters in Java.

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's not a method that does it in one call, but [`offsetByCodePoints()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#offsetByCodePoints%28int,%20int%29) will help you do this.

```
static String substring(String str, int idx, int len) {
  return str.substring(idx, str.offsetByCodePoints(idx, len));
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it have to be `substring(str.offsetByCodePoints(0, idx), str.offsetByCodePoints(0, idx+len))`?

Comment: It depends on whether the `idx` parameter is a character offset or a codepoint offset. The string methods generally take character offsets, and those that work with code points are aimed at converting code point offsets into character offsets.

Answer (score 0):

See java source at: `java.util.stream.Collectors#joining()`

```java
.codePoints().limit(255) // limit as you need
    .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, null)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation of your code to help others in the future